# Unable to use .contains() with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to filter a database column by a list of integers from a separate query in LINQ to entities. My code is below:

```
 var byProcs = db.ProcedureLabs.Where(x => x.LabID == labID).Select(x=>x.ProcID).ToList();
 var actProcs = db.Procedures.Where(x=>x.id.Contains(byProcs));
```

I want to take the list of byProcs and filters the actProcs. Both are integers.

When I try using the db.Procedures.Where(x=>x.id.Contains(byProcs)) I get the following error message:

> No overload for method 'Contains' takes 0 arguments.

I have looked at many examples of filtering a entry by a list of entries, and contains is always used, what am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the types of your variables and properties are, but I assume you are trying to do this:

```
db.Procedures.Where(x=>byProcs.Contains(x.id))
```

Comment: Wow. That was it. I had to reverse the order. Thanks!

Comment: @EliHellmer dont forget to upvote and select an answer

Comment: I attempted to and it says I must wait 11 minutes before accepting. I will accept here shortly when it allows me too!